# Habilitar botón a partir de un desplegable c#

Tags: c#, asp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo el html con el desplegable en el cual el usuario deberá obligatorio seleccionar alguna opción y despues de seleccionar habilitar el botón.

```
                              <asp:ListItem Selected="True" value="   "> </asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem value="Fallo Formación estuche"> Fallo Formación estuche </asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem value="Fallo Control(Cámaras)"> Fallo Control (Cámaras) </asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem value="Fallo Alimentación Propectos"> Fallo Alimentación Propectos </asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem value="Fallo Alimentación Producto"> Fallo Alimentación Producto </asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem value="Estuche Mal Cerrado"> Estuche Mal Cerrado </asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem value="Estuche Dañado"> Estuche Dañado </asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem value="Atasco"> Atasco </asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem value="Fallo Pesadora">Fallo Pesadora</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem value="Otro"> Otro </asp:ListItem>

                            </asp:DropDownList><br/><br/><br/>
                        </td>



 <td>
                      <asp:Button ID="btnParada"  onClick="Button_Parada" runat="server" Text="Parada" Class="ButtonAction AbreDialogFirma"
                      onMouseOver="this.className='ButtonActionOver';"
                      onmouseout="this.className='ButtonAction';" />  

                  </td>
```

¿Me puede echar una mano alguien? ¿como podría realizar esta función en C#?

```
 protected void DropListSelectedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e){

        btnParada.Enabled = true;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hace mucho que no uso este tipo de controles
pero con las propiedades siguientes:

```
 AutoPostBack="true"
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListSelectedChanged"
```

te servirá. En el servidor sería poner algo así

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void DropDownListSelectedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
         //Aqui tu código
        ...
    }
</script>
```

De esta forma puedes ir al servidor donde en C# podrás decirle a tu boton enabled = true Por poner un ejemplo.

Esto te lo pongo un poco de cabeza por que como te comento, hace tiempo que no uso esto.

Ahora bien, como recomendación te diría que quitases todo esto y usases html5 del tipo:

```
<select id="miLista">
   <option value="1">uno</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="2">dos</option>
</select>
```

y con javascript hacer toda la lógica necesaria, evitarás tener que ir al servidor para "tonterias" Ahorrarás trafico y tiempo del servidor.

```
<script>
    var listado = document.getElementById("miLista");
    //Lo que quieras hacer con la lista...
</script>
```

**Edit**

En la linea:

```
 <asp:ListItem values="Fallo Pesadora">Fallo Pesadora</asp:ListItem>
```

parece que existe un error **values** debes cambiarlo por **value**

Saludos.

Comment: No ha funcionado con esta forma. Debido a la interfaz de compilación que uso no puedo usar Javascript o html5.

Comment: Pues si no puedes usar javascript mal vamos, por que ese código que tienes, el compilador, hace eso por debajo. una cosa que puedes hacer, es ir a la web en concreto y ver cual es el HTML resultado de esa compilación y ver si te está fallando algo. (con el Chrome pulsando F12).

Comment: Estoy usando tracksys como interfaz, si lo he visto en modo consola y no veo error.

Comment: He creado un POC copiando y pegando tu código y he visto este fallo:                               <asp:ListItem values="Fallo Pesadora">Fallo Pesadora</asp:ListItem>
Es value no values. Si hago ese cambio el resto funciona como te decía en la respuesta. (Edito en la respuesta)

Comment: Realizado los cambios y sin resultados a lo mejor en el codigo c# estoy haciendo algo mal

Comment: Ya he encontrado el fallo mi culpa, no había puesto el handler en html. gracias